# org.HdrHistogram newbie questions

Tags: java, histogram

Just started to use hdr Histogram, some usage is not clear also not so much documentation. here are my questions (thanks for help for answering them):

a) What is the difference between AtomicHistogram and CouncurrentHistogram? I understand that in concurrent environment I need to use one of them - but which one I need to pick up in which scenario?

b) Why getStartTimestamp and getEndTimestamp in AbstractHistogram may be required?

c) What is the difference between DoubleHistogram, IntCountsHistogram and ShoftCountsHistogram. I can't just understand the world "resolution", I need to see clear picture with good simple example

d) Why I may need WriterReaderPhaser or SingleWriterDoubleRecorder and where to use it?

e) I want to record Disruptor (Ring buffer) queue size and I use simple Histogram class with recordValue(), but when I print output, it should values below 1 with decimal places. Why? Is HDR Histogram good to record disruptor size?

Thanks.